# How do I preserve python colors when generating an ".exe" file

Tags: python, colors

How to generate an exe file containing python inherit colors like in the example below?

```
    print('\033[32mHello World!\033[m')
```

Even when i tried the simple methods the colors arent shown. It just appears like that:

**\033[32mHello World!\033[m**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The more likely explanation is the terminal you're using is different. Not all terminals support ANSII escape codes. Try some different terminals.

Comment: Works in Linux Shell. You can use the Cross-Platform package called [Colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama)

Comment: @dsasd Thanks dude! Colorama worked for me! Its not the exactly same tunes but its merely a detail  :)